# Change a script post-execution in a for loop

Tags: python, linux, bash

This is a very dumb question. I have a python script that I am running on multiple files using a for loop:

`for i in *; do ./file.py -i $i -o $i"_out"; done`

Now, during this operation if I alter the script, will it change for the next execution in the loop ?

Comment: Yes it uses modified version of script. The best way for checking that is testing.

Comment: @Vahidabdi So it would pick the latest version in different iterations ofthe loop? The file is not cached, considering it is a loop?

Comment: @Vahidabdi.. yep it is the case.. I tested.. :)

Comment: But don't forget to quote ``"$i"``. Like this: ``for i in *; do ./file.py -i "$i" -o "${i}_out"; done``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will change for the next execution of the loop.

The shell re-reads and executes `./file.py` for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want:
let's try it by simple example

file.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
print 200 + int(sys.argv[1])
```

Bash

```
for i in `seq 10`; do ./file.py $i && sleep 1; done
```

OUTPUT:

```
101
102
# change the script in the middle
203
204
205
206
207
...
```